# Macro's "incomplete type not allowed" error?

Tags: c, visual-studio-macros

I have defined a macro having two parameter as given below:

```
#define DO_LIST_HEADER(Titem,MAX) typedef struct  {\
       int count;\
       Titem array[MAX];\
} TOrderedList##Titem;\
    \
void initialize_list##Titem(TOrderedList *list);\
int insert_item##Titem(TOrderedList *list, Titem item);\
int retrieve_ith##Titem(const TOrderedList *list, int i, Titem *item);\
int number_of_items##Titem(const TOrderedList *list);\
int list_empty##Titem(const TOrderedList *list);
```

This was in a header file and when I try to 'call' this macro from another `.c` file  including the header in it.

```
typedef Ttime Titem;

DO_LIST_HEADER(Ttime,10)
```

Here I get an error that says `incomplete type not allowed`.

Why am I getting this type of error?

`DO_LIST_HEADER` macro contains function prototype containing `Ttime` as parameter.

Comment: Are you including the definition of `Ttime` somewhere before that statement?

Comment: as you can see Ttime is defined in the header file.

Comment: @1011 what we can see is that `Titem` is defined in terms of `Ttime`, not the definition of `Ttime` itself.

Comment: No, we can't see it defined. We see **Titem** defined as Ttime.

Comment: Titem is defined in another header file which is included in this header file.

Comment: And TOrderedList is defined... ? Isn't the point of all this macro-conflagration to define something like *this*: `void initialize_list##Titem(TOrderedList##Titem *list);` Note the parameter.

Comment: TOrderList is defined inside the macro.

Comment: Um.. no it isn't. `TOrderedList##Titem` is defined in the macro. Do the substitution for `Ttime` and you have `TOrderedListTtime` as a struct type. Your parameter isn't using that. You *should*, but you don't in your case, because you left out the `##Titem`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I wrote my answer before I saw your comments, but you should consider converting your comments to an answer — I'd up-vote it for you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no worries. Hell, I up-voted *yours*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type names in the function declarations need to be pasted with the `##Titem` term too:

```
#define DO_LIST_HEADER(Titem,MAX) typedef struct  {\
       int count;\
       Titem array[MAX];\
} TOrderedList##Titem;\
    \
void initialize_list##Titem(TOrderedList##Titem *list);\
int insert_item##Titem(TOrderedList##Titem *list, Titem item);\
int retrieve_ith##Titem(const TOrderedList##Titem *list, int i, Titem *item);\
int number_of_items##Titem(const TOrderedList##Titem *list);\
int list_empty##Titem(const TOrderedList##Titem *list);
```

Comment: I was one step away from asking for the definition of MAX =P